# return from git stash to the previews state and order in the commits

Tags: git

I have git local repository with 10 commits,

I do `git reset --soft` on the third commit
and then `git stash`

when i do `git stash apply`
,i see all the commits together

how can i restore the state to 7 separated commits?

Comment: Search your reflog (`git reflog`) for the hash `HEAD` was pointing at before your `reset`, then `git log <thatHash>` to see them. Then `git reset --hard <thatHash>` if you want your branch to go back to this state.

Comment: Sounds like you should just leave your stuff in a branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because [`stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) doesn't store that information - it stores the working directory and index.

Your reset-followed-by-stash *specifically* flattened the sequence of commits into a single diff. If you know that you will want to recover the commits later, deliberately discarding them is the wrong way to go.

Having said that, all is not lost - if you look at [`reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), your old `HEAD` from before the reset is probably still there (called something like `HEAD@{2}`). The seven previous commits will still be reachable from it.

You can use `reset` again to simply roll forward to the previous head, or you can create a branch pointing to that ref, and merge or rebase as usual. It depends whether you made any changes since the original reset+stash.